# MS Access - How can I sum all of the records of one field and use that sum in a calculation in another field?

Tags: sum, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010, ms-query

MS Access query question - I am making a query to calculate the price of a finished good. To do so, the equation is ((sum of material cost)+(labor cost))/completed finished goods). The problem is that I need to first sum the material cost of each of the 5 materials and THEN use that number in the calculation above. How can I use this sum in another field *within the same query?* I want to avoid making a separate query if possible, but if not it's ok.

Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to add a sub query very easily. Use a TOTAL command to produce the value to be used in the other query.

Comment: @htm11h I built a sub-query but now I am getting a circular reference cause by my new sub-query. All I did was take the value from the original query, sum it up using the Totals button, then pass this value to the original query in an expression. Did I miss an important step??

Comment: How about posting your code?

Comment: I figured it out @htm11h, but thanks for the help!